# nodejs/express mongoose .populate() on schema with refs to itself

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have this schema for a User:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({

    ...

    friends: [{
        user: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'users'
        }
    }],
    sentRequests: [{
        user: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'users'
        }
    }],
    recievedRequests: [{
        user: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'users'
        }
    }]
}
```

Then when trying to show all the recievedRequests to a page I use this code:

```
router.get('/friendRequests', (req, res) => {
    User.findOne({
            _id: req.user.id
    })
    .populate('recievedRequests.user')
    .then(curUser => {
        res.render('friends/friendRequests', {
            curUser: curUser
        });
    })
});
```

where `User` is the model and `req.user.id` is the id of the currently logged in user. However, in the webpage whenever I reference `curUser.recievedRequests.user` it simply returns the id of the user and not the actual user object. I am assuming it has to do with the nested schema reference since I can't see anything else that would cause this issue. Does anyone know of a way to resolve this?

Thanks.

Comment: well, probably while you are settting up `req.user.id` over there you can set up other user metadata also. 
may be did not get what you are asking. can you please elaborate little more.

Comment: are you exporting your User model as `users` ?

Comment: @saikatchakrabortty I guess I could but then I'd have to query the database at least 3 times for every single http request made (since all I have is the user IDs) . Basically all I'm asking is why doesn't populate() work in this code.

Comment: @FarhanTahir Yes